How can I handle a situation where the user's selected font is not included in the SDK library?
When users edit a PDF, the text they add often doesn't match the original font, leading to inconsistencies. How can we address this issue effectively?
I have tried the following method, but it still doesn't feel quite right:

Packaging commonly used fonts into our technical package. However, there are always many unexpected text fonts, resulting in a poor user experience.


How do you edit the PDF? The editor application should provide/embed the required fonts.

A new feature allows for editing PDF content, including adding or deleting text. In the technology sector, PDF applications typically offer a variety of fonts, but cannot include all possible fonts within the app. I'm looking for an improved solution that enables users to edit PDF files as seamlessly as they would a Word document.

"A new feature allows for editing PDF content" - a new feature of what? Of your software? Of the PDF SDK you're using? Of a web SDK you're using? Please clarify.

New features of PDF SDK

Well, if it's a feature of the PDF SDK you're using, then the documentation of that SDK should show you how to use it. As it's a new feature, though, it might not yet be fully supported. If you tell us which PDF SDK you're talking about, someone knowledgeable in that SDK might be able to tell you more.
